# Is it possible to change resource folder location?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to change the location of the resource folder?

The project gets resources by accessing files from the resource path.

I have tried several solutions(to get the path), but none work, as the location/path seems to change depending on if you are debugging or not, and also which computer you are on.

Which is why i want to change it to a static location.

Comment: By any chance, are you reading resources using file APIs?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight just the c# file.readallbytes(path). the problem is the path changes, and we cant find a consistent method for getting it.

Comment: have you considered using embedded resources?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes, I have. but that would require changing a significant portion of the project.

Comment: @DOSLuke You should use embedded resources, that's how you get your program to be location-independent. You can also find the location from which your program is running, and use it to find where the resources are, but this solution is not as good as embedding resources into exe itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have said, switching to embedded resources is the best option. I have done a hybrid solution. Because so much of my project's code base relies on paths, I have switched to using embedded resources, but wrote a class that retrieves the file you ask for and copies it to a temporary location on the hard drive, and returns the path to it.

It is also somewhat thread safe, and cleans the temp folder once the first time the function is called on every new program start.

Please feel free to critique my work.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace blah
{
    //there could be a problem with VERY large files and running out of ram. if we end up having those,
    //switch to reading the resource stream and
    //appending the bytes to the file, instead of reading in full and writing in full.
    //-DOSLuke

    //instructions:

    //to add a resource:
    //add it like usual in the solution explorer
    //right click the newly added resource and click properties
    //under the 'build action' dropdown, select 'embedded resource'
    //then it is ready to be accessed.


    //to get a location on disk of a resource: ---this is what our program uses the most.
    //use ResourceHelper.GetResourceLocation("filename.extension");
    //for example:
    //ResourceHelper.GetResourceLocation("template.txt");


    //to obtain a raw resource stream for manipulation
    //ResourceHelper.GetResourceStream("template.txt");
    //this is the proper way of accessing resources


    //to get all the bytes from a resource via a resource stream:
    //ResourceHelper.ReadStreamFully(ResourceHelper.GetResourceStream("template.txt"));


    //what GetResourceLocation(string filename) is doing behind the scenes:
    //it starts by doing some possible cleaning of temp folder and some checking to make sure
    //the requested resource exists.
    //it gets or is given a resource stream (the proper way of accessing resources)
    //it gets all the bytes from the stream.
    //it saves all bytes into a file with the given filename that you are trying to access
    //it then returns the location of that temp file for you to use.
    //please note, that the file name doesnt matter, as long as the bytes in the file are exactly the same as the original resource file / embedded resource.
    //so basically it just copies the resource to a known location on disk and returns the location.

    class ResourceHelper
    {
        private static bool HasBeenCleanedOnce = false;
        private static object LockHolder = new object();

        public static string temppath = "temp_path_on_disk";

        public static string GetResourceLocation(string filename)
        {
            return GetResourceLocation(filename, GetResourceStream(filename));
        }

        public static string GetResourceLocation(string filename, Stream resourcestream)
        {
            lock (LockHolder) //this safely protects resources so only one thread (that locks with the locker object) can access the resource at a time
            {
                string place = temppath + filename;

                Directory.CreateDirectory(temppath);

                //it will only clean once close to the start of every program start
                if (!HasBeenCleanedOnce)
                {
                    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(temppath))
                        File.Delete(file);

                    HasBeenCleanedOnce = true;
                }

                if (!File.Exists(place))
                    File.WriteAllBytes(place, ReadStreamFully(resourcestream));

                return place;
            }
        }

        //gets a resource and returns a stream that can read it
        public static Stream GetResourceStream(string file)
        {
            string resourceName = "your_solution_name.Resources." + file;

            string[] resources = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();

            if (!resources.Contains(resourceName))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Resource '" + file + "' could not be found at '" + resourceName 
                    + "'. Did you add the resource and set the resource to be embedded?" 
                    + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "This will likely break after clicking 'ok'", "ERROR");
            }

            return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
        }

        //reads a stream fully and returns a byte[] array of the contents
        public static byte[] ReadStreamFully(Stream input)
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                input.CopyTo(ms);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should *really* consider switching to embedded resources as some comments have suggested. This would make referencing your individual resources **much** easier.

However, *if* you do not want to do that and *if* the path you are trying to get is consistent relative to the executable then you can use this method to find the path regardless of execution location.

Assuming the resources folder is in the same directory do:

```
// Change @"Resources\" to match the relative path from the exe.
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Resources\"));`
```

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` will return the directory path for the exe.
`directory` would now hold the path to the resources folder.

If your exe is in the path `C:\Program Files\MyAwesomeApp\`. Then `directory` would be equal to `C:\Program Files\MyAwesomeApp\Resources`.

If your files are not already being written out to the exe's location then make sure the `Copy to Output Directory` option for each file is set to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.

Comment: the path is not consistent relative to the exe. I tried using a similar solution, but on the machines we are designing for, the resources end up buried in the appdata folder for some reason.

Comment: How are these resources being deployed?

Comment: If you know this path at app install you could write the path to a config file or registry entry and reference that.

Comment: we publish the solution and install it on computers. we dont know at install.

Comment: How is your installer deploying the resource files?

Comment: i dont know. its visual studios publishing system.

Comment: How are you adding the resources added at design time then?

Comment: in the solution explorer, right clicking the resource folder and clicking add.

Comment: Ok, one thing you could do is on those files in visual studio click is in their properties change `Copy to Ouput Directory` to `Copy Always`. This will add them to a `Resources` folder in the executable directory which you can access using the method I posted above

Comment: as i said in my question, the resource directory changes. it is not consistent with the location of the exe.

Comment: Right, try doing what i said above though. Having those files flagged to copy to the output directory will create a resources folder automagically on build that, afaik, *is* consistently relative to the location of the exe. Should be in the same directory as the exe.

Comment: I have already started converting the project to use embedded resources. thanks though.

Comment: That's great! Good luck in your endeavor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Resources you mean: If you are referring to your localization Resources:

In your startup.cs:

```
services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
```

And add the folder resources to your root of your project.

If you are referring to other resources that aren't classes/interfaces. So things like text files you need to read and use in your application use:

```
// Use depency injection to be able to use HostingEnvironnement
HostingEnvironnemnt.ContentRootPath + "\wwwroot\textfile.txt";
```